# React hooks - useEffect method keeps fetching

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In many of my components, I have to use token from store to get data and represent it (header menu, footer menu, products on page, slider images, etc.). What I am trying to do is to get this data only if I don't have it, but React keeps sending requests every time token changes (as token is dependency), even though I clearly put condition and I can see it if I console.log it. What am I doing wrong?

```
const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
 if (!cities.length) {
  fetch(`.....&token=${props.token}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

    if (data.data.results) {
    setCities(data.data.results.cities)

    }
   })
  }
}, [props.token, cities.length]);
```

Comment: Since you set `cities` on every re-render, `cities` is always a new object, thus `cities.length` is not the same as the previous one. Also `if(!cities.length)` is always true since `cities` is always defined, initially the length is `0`, which still returns true. What you could do instead is `if(cities.length<1)`

Answer (score 2):

The `cities` will be empty on first render anyway, so you don't need to check for its length and specify it as a dependency:

```
const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`.....&token=${props.token}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.data.results) {
        setCities(data.data.results.cities)
      }
    })
}, [props.token]);
```

You can also memoize the token to prevent it from triggering the `useEffect` callback:

```
const token = useMemo(() => props.token, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

// EDITED BECAUSE OF THE COMMENTS

```
// should be outside of the function
let timesExecuted = 0

function fetch () {
useEffect(() => {
if(props.token){
 timesExecuted = timesExecuted + 1
}

if (timesExecuted === 1) {
  fetch(`.....&token=${props.token}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

    if (data.data.results) {
    setCities(data.data.results.cities)
    }
   })
  }
}, [props.token]);
}
```

SO IT WILL COME every time BUT BE EXECUTED ONLY WHEN prop.token IS OKEY (feel free to modify the first IF based on token validations).

Comment: It is to make sure that token is there, as token is also requested in other component.

Comment: do you need to get the cities every time the token changes?  Or you need it only 1 time ?

Comment: Only one time, but I don't know if I have token already in my store as it is also requested when app mounts. So basically I need it as a dependency, so when it is there, I send request.

Comment: Done i edited my answer based on your needs, feel free to upvote and mark as solution answer if it worked